# RequireJS replacing Node's Require method

Tags: node.js, requirejs, mocha.js

I'm running into an issue where node's require method has been replaced by requirejs' require method. We're running a backbone app and I've set up some mocha tests. The goal was to be able to run the tests in the browser, and also use grunt-mocha-test and run them in terminal on every build with grunt-contrib-watch.

I don't fully yet understand how all these pieces fit together, so please forgive any lack of explanation, understanding.

This is the set up of one of our test files, models.js:

```
describe("Models", function() {

  var should;
  var firstModule = 'models/firstModel';
  var secondModule = 'models/secondModel';
  var chaiModule = 'chai';

  modules = [
    firstModule,
    secondModule,
    chaiModule
  ];

  before(function(done) {
    require(modules, function(firstModel, secondModel, chai){
      FirstModel = eventModel;
      SecondModel = eventDetailsModel;
      should = chai.should();
      done();
    });
  });

  beforeEach(function(done) {
    NewFirstModel = new FirstModel();
    NewSecondModel = new SecondModel();
    done();
  });

  describe("first model", function() {

    it("should exist", function (done) {
      NewFirstModel.should.exist();
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Using grunt-contrib-requirejs with these settings:

```
compile:
  options:
    baseUrl: "<%= tmpDir %>/scripts"
    mainConfigFile: "<%= tmpDir %>/scripts/init.js"
    name: "../../bower_components/almond/almond"
    out: "<%= distDir %>/scripts/app.js"
    preserveLicenseComments: false
    cjsTranslate: true
    wrapShim: true
    uglify:
      ascii_only: true
```

The mochaTest grunt task:

```
test:
  options:
    reporter: 'spec',
  src: ['app/test/*.js']
```

I've got a test.html file which includes each individual test file and properly tests everything I throw at them.

However, when I run the mochaTest grunt task, which points to the same test files, I get the following error:

```
AssertionError: path must be a string
```

referring to this line in models.js:

```
require(modules, function(firstModel, secondModel, chai){
```

If I console log the require method, it comes back as RequireJS' require method. I've tried a few different things, including setting `nodeRequire: require` in the init.js file referenced in the requirejs config. Any clues? Thanks!!!

Comment: Everything indicates that you are running this in Node.js, and not in a browser. So why on earth are you optimizing your modules (i.e. using `grunt-contrib-requirejs`)?? And you seem to be bundling Almond into the optimized bundle, which I do not believe works with Node.js.

Comment: Yes, this is running in node for serving files, making api calls, etc. However, this is a single page backbone app run in the browser.

Comment: It seems you are mixing frontend & backend modules. Use requirejs for your frontend modules (that run in the browser) only.